# How Do I connect two separate routes with a line using Leaflet?

Tags: r, leaflet

| Observation | originlat | originLong | endLat | endLong |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 31.36445 | 121.60415 | 33.7372 | -118.22531 |
| A | 41.3459 | 2.17599 | 20.14076 | 57.48244 |

These are the coords. When I select A it just connects all points together. I want the first 2 points connected separately as well as the second ones.

```
leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addCircleMarkers(
        lng = c(originLong, endLong),
        lat = c(originlat, endLat)
      ) %>%
      addPolylines( lng = c(originLong, endLong),
                    lat = c(originlat, endLat))})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have saved the data in a data frame called `df`. In order to show multiple lines in the `leaflet` map, you can loop over the values in your data frame and call `addPolyLines()` from within.

The code will look like this:

```
map <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(
    lng = c(df$originLong, df$endLong),
    lat = c(df$originlat, df$endLat)
  ) 

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  map <- map %>% addPolylines(lng = c(df[i,]$originLong, df[i,]$endLong),
                              lat = c(df[i,]$originlat, df[i,]$endLat))
}
```

The output will look like this:

[image]